# Laravel Tinker Not Working After Upgrading From 5.3 To 5.4

Tags: laravel

I recently upgrade Laravel 5.3 to Laravel 5.4. I had read the upgrade guide provided by the laravel, and everything looks good. Until I try to run the Laravel Tinker and it's not working. I already followed the upgrade guide specifically for Laravel Tinker part.

> Laravel Tinker
>
> In order to continue using the tinker Artisan command, you should also
>   install the laravel/tinker package:
>
> composer require laravel/tinker
>
> Once the package has been installed, you should add
>   Laravel\Tinker\TinkerServiceProvider::class to the providers array in
>   your config/app.php configuration file.

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade

And here is my config/app.php :

```
'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        Laravel\Tinker\TinkerServiceProvider::class,
```

But then, when I ran the command "php artisan tinker", it says this:

```
 [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
  Command "tinker" is not defined.
```

Has anybody experienced this before?

Note: other artisan command works perfectly and I can see my site just fine.

Comment: Check `php artisan --version` for your exact Laravel version, and your your composer.lock file (or `composer show laravel/tinker`) for the version of laravel/tinker you've installed.

Comment: I have the same problem , i looked a solution here but still not working for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42635016/command-tinker-is-not-defined

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> **Laravel Tinker**
>
> In order to continue using the tinker Artisan command, you should also install the laravel/tinker package:
>
> `composer require laravel/tinker`
>
> Once the package has been installed, you should add `Laravel\Tinker\TinkerServiceProvider::class` to the providers array in your config/app.php configuration file.

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade

Answer (score 5):

Edit your `app/Console/Kernel.php`, then modify the `$commands` property with this:

```
protected $commands = [
    //
    \Laravel\Tinker\Console\TinkerCommand::class,
];
```

then in console, make a

```
composer dump-autoload
```