# Laravel console like rails

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have began to study "Laravel". I have already learned ruby on rails framework. Rails have console where you can create models and run all the commands your script runs. It is very useful and i am really used to this. I am interested if "Laravel" has anything like this, to create my objects and check if validations work correctly or run  commands like 
"Post.all" where post is my object to retrieve all data from database.

Comment: Are you maybe looking for Artisan CLI? https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/artisan

Comment: yes i think that is what i have been looking for but i have another problem. when i try to access to my objects for example Post it says that it is undefined. can you give me a solution for that?

Comment: @ditojanelidze are you using the full namespace of the class?

Comment: depending on how your classes are set up, try `\App\Post::all()`

Answer (score 3):

The Rails console is based on Interactive Ruby Shell (IRB) which is a read–eval–print loop (REPL) environment. There is an equivalent in Laravel (based off of psysh):

```
php artisan tinker
```

Note that 'Tinker' appears to be included in [Laravel 5.7](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/artisan#tinker) (current at time of writing), but was removed in some previous versions. It can be installed with these instructions:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41888190/1512654